# PHP post lagging

Tags: vb.net, post

I have a code to make php posts.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox3.ReadOnly = True
    If TextBox2.Text = ("") Then
    Else
        Dim postData = "msg=" & TextBox3.Text & ": " & TextBox2.Text & "&token=" & TextBox1.Text
        Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.2.7/msg.php")
        request.Method = "POST"
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        TextBox2.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

but it when it runs the application is freezing. When i send a post locally it's not doing that.
Any way to prevent that?
MY full code:
http://pastebin.com/GTtDAuTM

Comment: Comment your code. Tell us where it is freezes and what it does

Comment: check the pastebin that i posted

Comment: @T.S. ......................